# Page reloading in flutter web causes an error

Tags: flutter

I'm implementing an admin dashboard using flutter web. As I have many types of admins, I register the admin's data in `getIt` if login is successful and I use the admin name in all pages. But when reloading a page by clicking the 'reload' button in the browser or hot reload or hot restart, it gives be an error saying that the `User` type isn't registered in the `getIt` instance.
May I get help, please?

```
Future<void> adminLogin(
      BuildContext context, String email, String password) async {
    emit(LoginLoading());
    Either<String, void> response =
        await repository.adminLogin(email, password);
    response.fold((errorMessage) {
      emit(LoginFailure());
      showFailureToast(errorMessage);
    }, (_) {
      emit(LoginSuccess());
      setupUser(
        User(name: 'Admin'),
      );
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(
        DashboardScreen.routeName,
      );
    });
  }
```

```
void setupUser(User user){
  getIt.registerSingleton<User>(user);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the relevant code, especially where you register your user with `GetIt`?

Comment: @BenWeschler I edited the quest with the code.